# How can I save and copy a screenhot at the same time?

Tags: gnome, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

Ive been trying to use gnome-screenshot like so

`gnome-screenshot -acf $(date +%y_%h_%d_%H_%M_%S)`

if I use the copy argument gnome-screenshot will not save. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, it seems `-c` and `-f` don't work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -f is cancelled by the -c:

```
OPTIONS
   -c, --clipboard
          Send the grab directly to the clipboard.

   -f, --file=FILENAME
          Save screenshot directly to this file.
```

The file will be stored in memory, not on disk, when -c is used: if you open Libreoffice writer and paste you will see your image.

> How can I save and copy a screenshot at the same time?

edit1: [bugreport #1446650](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1446650) but nobody bothered to follow up on this.
edit2: I found a way around it by using xclip. Install with ...

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

and expand your command with a variable holding date and time and 2 commands:

```
DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'`
sleep 5 && gnome-screenshot -af $DATE && xclip -selection clipboard -t  image/png -i $DATE
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work in terminal, but it's not working as a keyboard shortcut. Even more troubling than that, when I try to assign the shortcut to the printscreen key a screenshot is taken instead. I disabled the screenshot shortcuts so I'm not sure why I cant use the printscreen key.

Comment: Convert the code into a script, make it executable, and *then* assign a keyboard shortcut to that script.

Comment: @DKBose That worked, thank you!