# gnome-screenshot not making sound with -f option

Tags: 19.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

When I run `gnome-screenshot`, the tool flashes the screen and takes a screenshot. When I run

```
gnome-screenshot -f <location>
```

which is supposed to save the screenshot at `<location>`, the screen flashes but there is no sound. Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Sounds like a bug  to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason but here's a workaround assuming it fits your workflow for taking screenshots:

```
gnome-screenshot -f $HOME/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png & paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga
```

should bring back the sound and save a time-stamped .png file in the specified location which is *~/Pictures* in the example above.

Notes:

- you may need to include the code in a script and then assign a shortcut keyboard combination to the script because, in some cases, certain codes don't work when used directly in keyboard shortcuts. (See the comments to the answer in [How can I save and copy a screenhot at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135631/how-can-i-save-and-copy-a-screenhot-at-the-same-time).)
- I used `&` instead of `&&` to get the sound to play without a lag. `&&` is normally used to ensure the previous command completes successfully.